# Rewards to $40. Is it best to get PayPal, prepaid Visa or Amazon card?

Tags: canada, paypal, reward-program

I can get $40 from Receipt Hog. They can give it as a prepaid Visa card, to my PayPal or Amazon gift card. Which is the best option of the 3? I was thinking PayPal and transferring it to my local bank account, but not sure what fees might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal will transfer funds to your bank account with no fees, it takes 1-3 business days. You can transfer immediately for a small fee. Your bank may charge fees to work with PayPal, and obviously you'd have to wait a little longer for bank validation if you haven't added your bank account yet.

The other options are also viable - prepaid Visa cards are accepted almost anywhere (especially post-2020 where many places have moved to cashless) and if you shop at Amazon, gift cards to Amazon are valuable.

Since there are no fees for any of these, you get the same value ($40) no matter which way you take your rewards.

Comment: Great, thanks! I forgot to mention I'm concerned that if I go with Visa or Amazon giftcard, can it be combined with another form of payment? For example if my purchase is $50, can I spend the complete $40 on the giftcard and pay the remainder some other way? I want to avoid the situation where I have to lose some money or find something that's $40.00 exactly, if that makes sense.

Comment: For Amazon, yes; the gift card balance is taken off first and the remaining balance can be paid by any other payment method. For the Visa card, it seems to depend on the merchant; we have been using reloadable prepaid cards due to cashless policies and just found out this weekend we can't use the small balance ($1.20 or so) we have left on a card because they can't split payment like that. Most merchants can.